# Replace current primary dns server without downtime

Tags: replace, domain-name-system, bind

I'm planning to upgrade my primary dns server. To avoid a downtime i'm planning to create vps where i will have same configured dns server. Till i reboot primary dns server i'm planing to change  VPS dns server's ip to what Primary dns has so all the traffic and query should answer the new vps dns server. Is this a good plan ? Actually i do not know how to perform this i'm afraid i will miss something . . .   P.s   i have authoritative dns zones.

All i want is to replace Primary dns server temporary to avoid downtime just need a simple way how to do this.

I'm using bind.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use that plan (an IP switch) if you want to have 100% uptime.

What you need to do is go to your registrar and add a second name server with the ip of your backup that youre temporarily creating. Then after your work on the primary is done, go back to the registrar and remove the backup.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up a secondary name server as a slave.  You can use your VPS
2. Contact your registrar to add your secondary name server (verify with dig -t ns yourdomain.tld)
3. Wait for your new secondary nameserver to appear on the root servers for your top level domain
4. Shutdown your primary nameserver
5. Upgrade your primary nameserver
6. Start up your primary nameserver
7. Remove your secondary nameserver from your registrar
8. Shutdown your secondary nameserver

I'd definitely consider having a more permanent solution to a secondary nameserver as a slave to avoid all this hassle going forward.

Any questions, just ask.